# WatchKit: Custom WKInterfaceButton Class failing with exc_bad_access whenever calling a function on it

Tags: swift, storyboard, watchkit

I have this custom button:

```
class LocationButton: WKInterfaceButton {

    func test() {
    print("HERE")
    }
}
```

And I try to use it in place of a WKInterfaceButton. In my Storyboard I have:

Custom Class

Class: LocationButton

Module: MyApp_WatchKit_Extension

And I have the following IBOutlet:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var myButton: LocationButton!

 @IBAction func myButtonClicked() {
     myButton.test()
 }
```

So when I click on this button it's supposed to call that test function. However, I get `exc_bad_access` every time.

Is creating/using a custom class as a button even possible with WatchKit?

EDIT: I should note, that by debugging I can see that myButton is not nil. The outlet is working

Answer (score 1):

The documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacebutton says “Do not subclass or create instances of this class yourself.”

Seems like that would explain your error.